how can I use Ubuntu 24.04 remote login for hyper-v enhanced session?
Trying to use Ubuntu 24.04 built-in remote login. It works :-) I can RDP to a Hyper-V based Ubuntu 24.04 guest machine from its Windows 11 host. However, when trying to connect from Windows Hyper-V Manager - I don't get an enhanced session. Seems like I need a vsocket connection vs. regular tcp connection used by RDP. Any way to change that? Do I have to install XRDP support even though Ubuntu 24.04 has native remote login support? (Enhanced session works for me on an Ubuntu 22.04 with XRDP installed on that very same Hyper-V.)

As far as we know, the gnome remote login is not providing all the features provided by xRDP.  We really like the gnome remote login as out of the box solution but lacks indeed support for drive redirection and interaction with Hyper-v Enhanced mode and possibility to reconnect to an existing remote session
If you need enhanced mode, we would recommend to stick to xRDP software.
Please note also that xRDP and Gnome Remote login can conflict with each others (they are using the same ports i.e. 3389 by default).  This can be changed to avoid any issues
Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Any link to an official guide for using xRDP with hyper-v for enhanced session on Ubuntu 24.04? The Quick Create option on hyper-v doesn't have 24.04 so I'm looking for the official manual instructions I should follow.

Found this repo now has instructions for installing on Ubuntu 24.04 as well. See here. Worked for me :-)

I had this issue as well and tried everything to no avail. The only solution I found was by following the steps below as an Ubuntu upgrade:

First creating the Ubuntu 22.04 from the Quick Create option in
Hyper-V manager

Setting the maximum size of the hard drive to a
large enough amount to have the minimum space needed for upgrading

Updating the main partition in the VM to reflect the available
storage Run sudo do-release-upgrade NOTE: Trying to upgrade from the software update GUI does not seem to work. Make sure apt and apt-get are fully updated as well.

When it updates all the packages during the upgrade it will ask to install xrdp udates select N and do not update anything when it asks during the upgrade when I tried to have it upgrade xrdp, the enhanced connection failed.

It will ask where to install GNOME, I installed in all the locations listed to be safe (2 in total).

It will ask to reboot. Once you reboot, it takes 5-10 minutes before the xrdp becomes available. It may seem like it is taking a while but it should work.


